# auto scale docker swarm in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Any help on auto scale docker swarm in GCP. Was trying for a reference link or coe sample for the same.

Can't fin a simplest link to use `docker API`

Comment: Docker Swarm doesn't support auto-scaling out of the box. You could leverage Managed Instance Groups to automatically create new worker nodes based on parameters like CPU utilization, and join them to the cluster with docker swarm join when booting. 

You can also take a look at GKE to see if it fits better your use case

Comment: any api reference of getting GCP Managed Instance Groups CPU, memory. Sould i check for 1 or all average. Anyone already did similar.

Comment: did that,, few issues how do we scale a service, based on the cpu/memory of that services alone, NOT of the node, cpu may be more of the service but not of the node. Second, after adding to the instance group, how to update the specific service with docker service update abc-service(specific service ??? ) repica=6.. to 7 (increment this one)